# Items in HTML table are not working properly

Tags: html, html-table

```
<table summary="" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: medium;">DATE</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: medium;">HOME</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: medium;">AWAY</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: medium;">TIP</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: medium;">FT</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: medium;">ODD</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" width="20" height="20" />/<img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/cross_red.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">01.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Doxa</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Nea Salamis </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1 </span></strong></td>
<td><strong>2-0</strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2.20 </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">02.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">FC OSS</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Achiles </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">0-2 </span></strong></td>
<td><strong>0-1</strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2.00</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">03.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Erfut</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Wehen </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2 </span></strong></td>
<td><strong>3-0</strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2.60 </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/cross_red.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">04.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Aalst</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Mouscron</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2-3</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2.35</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;"><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></span></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">05.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Portugal U21</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Norway U21</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">5+</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">5-1</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">6.50</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;"><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></span></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">06.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Estonia</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Holland</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">4+</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2-2</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2.10</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;"><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></span></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">07.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Vlasim</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Mas Toborsko</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">0-3</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">3.15</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">08.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Siena</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Bari</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">3+</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">3-2</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2.00</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">09.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Saudiska Arabia</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Emmen</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Trinidad i Tobag</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">o</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">FC Oss</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2/2</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1-3</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">5-0</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">7.50</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2.00</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">10.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Macedonia</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Scottland</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1-2</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2.40</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/cross_red.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">11.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Kecskemeti</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Ujpest</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2-1</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2.00</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">12.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Keflavik</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Tubize</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Akranes</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Antwerp</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">3+</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">3+</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">5-4</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">0-2</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.62</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.77</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong><strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/cross_red.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">13.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Borna Coric</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Koge</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Andy Murray</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Hvidovre</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">25.5 under</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1X</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">24</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2-0</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.85</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.25 </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">14.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Sunderland</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Torino</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Arsena</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">l</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Milan</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">X2</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1-3</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2-2</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;"> </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.80</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.25</span></strong></td>
<td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">15.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Barcelona B</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">.</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Reading</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Real Madrid B.</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Brighton</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1X</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2-0</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">0-0</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.75</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.33</span></strong></td>
<td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">16.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Auxerre</span></strong></td>
<td><strong style="line-height: 19px;"><span style="font-size: small;">Brest</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">X</span></strong></td>
<td><strong style="line-height: 19px;"><span style="font-size: small;">0-0</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">3.25</span></strong></td>
<td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">17.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Kalev</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Taura</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">s</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">FC Kopenhagen</span></strong></td>
<td><strong style="line-height: 19px;"><span style="font-size: small;">Flora</span></strong><strong style="line-height: 19px;"><span style="font-size: small;">Banga</span></strong><strong style="line-height: 19px;"><span style="font-size: small;">Juventus</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2&amp;3+</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2&amp;3+</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2</span></strong></td>
<td><strong style="line-height: 19px;"><span style="font-size: small;">1-1</span></strong><strong style="line-height: 19px;"><span style="font-size: small;">1-2</span></strong><strong style="line-height: 19px;"><span style="font-size: small;">1</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">-1</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.55</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.5</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">5</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.45</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/cross_red.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong></strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /><strong></strong><strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/cross_red.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">18.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Austria Vienna</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Marseille</span></strong></td>
<td><strong style="line-height: 19px;"><span style="font-size: small;">Porto</span></strong><strong style="line-height: 19px;"><span style="font-size: small;">Arsenal</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">X</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2</span></strong></td>
<td><strong style="line-height: 19px;"><span style="font-size: small;">0-1</span></strong><strong style="line-height: 19px;"><span style="font-size: small;">1-2</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.60</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.40</span></strong></td>
<td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">19.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">S.Tiraspol</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Anzhi</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">DNB1</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">0-0</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2.20</span></strong></td>
<td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">20.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Bres</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">t</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Le Poire</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Vannes</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Bastia</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Orleans</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Parris FC</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1X</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">X2</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">X2</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2-</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">0</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">0-2</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">3-0</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.2</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">0</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.50</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.40</span></strong></td>
<td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /><strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/cross_red.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">21.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Scunthorpe</span></strong></td>
<td><span style="font-size: small;"><b>Plymouth</b></span></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1-0</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2.10</span></strong></td>
<td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">22.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Corinthians</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Cruzerio</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">0-0</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2.90</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/cross_red.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">23.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Astra</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Cehlalul</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1/1&amp;3+</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">0-0</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">4.10</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/cross_red.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">24.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Barcelona
Atl.Madrid
Man. City
Swidon</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Real Sociedad
Osasuna
Wigan
Chelsea</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1
1
1
2</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">4-1
2-1
5-0
0-2</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.17
1.22
1.30
1.44</span></strong></td>
<td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" />
<img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" />
<img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" />
<img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">25.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Granada</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Sevilla</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Bologna</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">Chievo</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">Lazio</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">Napol</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">i</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">WBA</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Valencia</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Vallecano</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">AC Milan</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">Juventus</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">Catania</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">Sassuolo</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">Arsenal</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">X2</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1X</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">X2</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">X2</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">1X</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">1/1</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">X2</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">0-1</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">4-1</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">3-3</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">1-2</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">3-1</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">1-1</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">1-1</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.40</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.11</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.33</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.10</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.18</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.62</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.30</span></strong></td>
<td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" />
<img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" />
<img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" />

<strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/cross_red.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong></strong>

<strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></strong></strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">26.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Atl.Bilbao</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Villareal</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Betis</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Espanyol</span></strong></td>
<td><span style="font-size: small;"><b>GG</b></span><span style="font-size: small;"><b>0-2</b></span></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2-1</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2-1</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.67</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.80</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></strong></strong></strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/cross_red.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">28.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Angers</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Nancy</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">Bursaspor</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Tours</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Arles</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">Akhisar</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">X</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">X</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1-1</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">0-0</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">0-0</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">3.30</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">2.00</span></strong>

<strong><span style="font-size: small;">3.50</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></strong></strong></strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/cross_red.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong>

<strong><strong><strong><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></strong></strong></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">29.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;"> </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;"> </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;"> </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;"> </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;"> </span></strong></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">30.09.2013</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;"> </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;"> </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;"> </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;"> </span></strong></td>
<td><strong><span style="font-size: small;"> </span></strong></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is my table and I'm having a problem with the elements. (some of them)

First, some of the elements are sticking together. I want them to be separated, but they are added together for some reason.

Take a look at picture below
[image: first picture]

If you see for date 14.09.2013, they are supposed to be in this way:

Sunderland Arsenal 2 1-3 1.80

Torino Milan X2 2-2 1.25

But for some reason they stick together!

And second, the icon for the specific line is not showing on the proper line. See image below.

[image: second picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in this markup:

```
<strong><span style="font-size: small;">Sunderland</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Torino</span></strong>
```

That would cause "Sunderland" and "Torino" to be separated.  There isn't even a space between them.

As for the images not aligned with the text, you'll really want to break those lines into their own rows if you ever want that to work properly.  Something like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="7" style="vertical-align: top;"><strong><span style="font-size: small;">25.09.2013</span></strong></td>

    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Granada</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Valencia</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">X2</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">0-1</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.40</span></strong></td>
    <td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Sevilla</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Vallecano</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1X</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">4-1</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.11</span></strong></td>
    <td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Bologna</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">AC Milan</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">X2</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">3-3</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.33</span></strong></td>
    <td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Chievo</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Juventus</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">X2</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1-2</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.10</span></strong></td>
    <td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Lazio</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Catania</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1X</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">3-1</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.18</span></strong></td>
    <td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Napol</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: small;">i</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Sassuolo</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1/1</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1-1</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.62</span></strong></td>
    <td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/cross_red.png?180422" width="20" height="20" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">WBA</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">Arsenal</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">X2</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1-1</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span style="font-size: small;">1.30</span></strong></td>
    <td><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/necoB

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't abuse of creating unnecessary extra HTML tags.
2. Abuse on using CSS.
3. `Strong` & `span` are "inline" elements. What means that a sequence of them will be positioned side-by-side - like the letters in a text.
   In the otherside, there are "block" elements, like `div`, that breaks line after your content - like a paragraph in a text.

See http://jsfiddle.net/p7fKf/

CSS

```
div, img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
div {
    height: 30px
}
```

HTML

```
<table summary="" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="center" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <div>14.09.2013</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>Sunderland</div>
            <div>Torino</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>Arsenal</div>
            <div>Milan</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>X2</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>1-3</div>
            <div>2-2</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>1.80</div>
            <div>1.25</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></div>
            <div><img alt="" src="http://static.fortumo.com/images/tick_green.png?180422" /></div>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using Wordpress.com and they don't allow CSS for free users. Therefore I have to use HTML only. Any solution for that?

Comment: Why stack divs repeatedly to present what actually IS nested tabular data?

Comment: plus.. creating nested table, the css of table may change and he`d need patching them to match original table (like table borders)

Comment: Semantically, this is tabular data - all of the reasons not to use tables for layout fail in the face of being actual tables of data. Since he's forced by environmental constrains to use inline styles, stacked-divs and nested tables end up being similarly ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Your markup which is "sticking together" is doing exactly what the markup says it should.

If you want a line break within your <td>, you need to mark up the content with those line breaks. Since you are actually presenting tabular data, nested tables seem like the appropriate technique for this:

```
<tr>
    <td>DATE</td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>first-match-info</tr>
                <tr>second-match-info</tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
<tr>
```

Your presentation logic that generates the HTML will need a little massaging though.